# Google Adwords | excludedPlacementList -> addExcludedPlacement won't work with Urls that work via the UI

Tags: javascript, url, invalid-argument, google-ads-api

Let `list` denote an `ExcludedPlacementList`. Consider a *Placement-Url* (*eg* extracted from the `Domain` / `Url` column of a `URL_PERFORMANCE_REPORT` report) of the form `'mobileapp::2-test.bla.com'`. If I go to [https://adwords.google.com/aw/placementexclusionlists/detail?] and enter the placement `mobileapp::2-test.bla.com`, it works. An entry is generated. So **why** does it not work via the script command (Google Adwords Api):

`list.addExcludedPlacement('mobileapp::2-test.bla.com')`

? When I call this, I get the error

> Placement-URLs müssen in einem gültigen URL-Format angegeben werden

I even tried to call instead

`list.addExcludedPlacement('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=test.bla.com')`

That didn’t work either.

---

On the side… Is there a way to suggest to Google developers to fix this, so that the above command is possible?

Comment: Is this AdwordsScript or using the Adwords API?

Comment: @dorian It’s using the Script editor directly in a Google Adwords account. The particular selector/iterator mentioned above is this one https://developers.google.com/adwords/scripts/docs/reference/adwordsapp/adwordsapp_excludedplacementlist .

Comment: I see, then I unfortunately don't really have anything more to offer than checking out the Adwords Script forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/adwords-scripts